# TypeError: Chart.defaults.global.tooltips is undefined in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, chart.js

I am facing the error in webpage "TypeError: Chart.defaults.global.tooltips is undefined". I have explored the options to fix it, but couldn't make it.
Below is my code.

server.js

```js
var express = require('/root/node_modules/express');
var mongojs = require('/root/node_modules/mongojs');
var d3 = require('/root/node_modules/d3');
var morgan = require('/root/node_modules/morgan');             // log requests to the console (express4)
var bodyParser = require('/root/node_modules/body-parser');    // pull information from HTML POST (express4)
var methodOverride = require('/root/node_modules/method-override');

var db = mongojs('migration', ['hadoop_s3_mig']);

var app = express();
//var search = require('./search.js')

//app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));                 // set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users
app.use(morgan('dev'));                                         // log every request to the console
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended':'true'}));            // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.json());                                     // parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' })); // parse application/vnd.api+json as json
app.use(methodOverride());

app.get('/home', function(req,res) {
        console.log("I received a GET request in / dir");
        db.hadoop_s3_mig.find(function (err, docs) {

        var filtered_data = docs.filter(function (el) { return el.status == 'N'; });
        var occurences = d3.nest()
                .key(function(d) { return d.platformName; })
                .rollup(function(leaves) { return leaves.length; })
                .entries(filtered_data);

        console.log(filtered_data);
        console.log(occurences);
        res.json([filtered_data, occurences]);

        });

});

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
res.sendfile('./public/index.html'); // load the single view file (angular will handle the page changes on the front-end)
});

var portNumber = 3002;
app.listen(portNumber);
console.log('Server Running on port ' + portNumber);
```

```html
<!-- HTML File (./public/index.html) -->

<html>

   <head>
      <title>Angular JS Views</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>

<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.1.1/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.js"></script>

   </head>

   <body>

      <div ng-app = "mainApp">

               <nav class="navbar" style="background-color: #b2cade;>
                        <a class="collapse navbar-collapse" href="#">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li><img src="hadoop.jpg" width="100px" height="100px"></li>
                                <li><img src="AWS_S3.png" width="100" height="100"></li>
                        </ul>
                        <h1 align="center"> Angular JS </h1>
                        </a>
                </nav>
                <nav class="navbar navbar-light" style="background-color: #ff8080;">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                        <li><a href="#home"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#technical"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks">
                                                       </span> Technical DataSet Status </a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#business"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase">
                                                </span> Business DataSet Status </a></li>
                                </ul>
                        </div>
                </nav>


         <div ng-view></div>

         <script type = "text/ng-template" id = "home.htm">
            <h2> Platform and File Names</h2>

            <div class="container">
                        <table class="table">
                                <thead>
                                      <tr>
                                        <th>Platform Name</th>
                                        <th>File Name</th>
                                      </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                        <tr ng-repeat="filtered_data in filtered_data">
                                                <td>{{filtered_data.platformName}}</td>
                                                <td>{{filtered_data.name}}</td>

                                        </tr>
                                </tbody>
                        </table>
              </div>
         </script>

         <script type = "text/ng-template" id = "technical.htm">
            <h2> File Count based on Platform Name</h2>
            {{message}}

            <canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar"
              chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels"> chart-series="series"
            </canvas>
          </script>

         <script type = "text/ng-template" id = "business.htm">
            <h2> Business DataSets</h2>
            {{message}}
         </script>
      </div>

      <script>

var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", ["ngRoute", "chart.js"]);
//var angular = require('/root/node_modules/angular');
//var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute']);
         mainApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.

            when('/home', {
               templateUrl: 'home.htm',
               controller: 'HomeController'
            }).

            when('/technical', {
               templateUrl: 'technical.htm',
               controller: 'TechnicalController'
            }).
            when('/business', {
               templateUrl: 'business.htm',
               controller: 'BusinessController'
            }).

            otherwise({
               redirectTo: '/home'
            });
         }]);

         mainApp.controller('HomeController', function($scope, $http) {
            $http.get('/home').success(function (response) {
                console.log("I got the data requested");
                $scope.filtered_data = response[0];
               $scope.occurences = response[1];
            });

         });

         mainApp.controller('TechnicalController', function($scope) {
            $scope.message = "New Technical Controller";

              $scope.labels = ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012'];
              $scope.series = ['Series A', 'Series B'];
              $scope.data = [
                [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
                [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
              ];
         });

         mainApp.controller('BusinessController', function($scope) {
            $scope.message = "New Business Controller";
         });

</script>

   </body>
</html>
```

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Thanks
Gowthaman J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same issue... 
I suppose its something with the versions of both angular and chart js. From the [docs](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/) it is recommended to use **AngularJS (requires at least 1.4.x)** and **Chart.js (requires Chart.js 2.x)**. I had no such issues with Anguar 1.6.4 and chart js 2.6.0 till I updated Angular to 1.6.6. However the error you got is by use of chartJs less than version 2. For me I am getting a different error with angular 1.6.6... i.e.

```
TypeError: arcOpts is undefined
```